# fields entry in ref/StreamPlot

Tags: front-end, formatting, keyboard, display, palettes

In the ref/StreamPlot help file in Mathematica 10.0.2, we see the following image:

[image]

Can someone explain how I would type this into an input cell?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is this a typesetting question or a StreamPlot question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To type this into *Mathematica* and have it displayed in the same way, you can either use the `Column` and `Row` from the "Typesetting" part of one of the first three Pallets
[image: Pallets]

or use their keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>.

Comment: Amazing! Great answer. I used the Basic Math Assistant, but I chose the one just above the one you shaded. It worked perfectly, along with the Tab key and Ctrl+Return. I also learned that Ctrl+, adds a new column.